# system aggregation issue in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

After deploying the app on App store we are getting the below error constantly and app is getting crashed. Below is the error.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'System.AggregateException', reason: 'System.AggregateException: A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task or accessing its Exception property. As a result, the unobserved exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread. ---> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
>   Object name: 'MobileAuthenticatedStream'.
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x1030e7990 + 0x00028> in :0 
>     at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream+d__58.MoveNext () <0x10341f300 + 0x005ff> in <24ab45aca3bd43dca88a4166f90ed49f#ccefd9b888727970fe79a7fe74005423>:0 
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
>   Object name: 'MobileAuthenticatedStream'.
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x1030e7990 + 0x00028> in :0 
>     at Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream+d__58.MoveNext () <0x10341f300 + 0x005ff> in <24ab45aca3bd43dca88a4166f90ed49f#ccefd9b888727970fe79a7fe74005423>:0 <---
>   '

The users which have this issue they are using iPhone 8 plus with OS version 11.2.6. However we are not able to get this issue on previous versions of iPhone.

Does this error related to device OR xamarin ?

Any help on this appreciated !

Comment: Are you using some sort of `async await` pattern, on your app....to me it seems that you in some place started a task but you are not awaiting for its completion.

Comment: Have you contacted Xamarin support about this? Seems like it may be a bug in their mobile authentication system.

Comment: @Hackerman yes we are using async await to send/receive data from web api. so what changes we need to do ?

Comment: @RonBeyer They are getting logged in successfully.. while using the app its crashing... do we need to update xamarin packages? which i read in some link

Comment: Also the message `System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'MobileAuthenticatedStream'` should give you a clue...maybe you are assigning that object inside a `using` statement and when you are trying to access the object it is disposed...or maybe an exception occurs that trigger some garbage collection on that object; you need to ensure your code runs inside a try catch finally block in order to avoid these kind of scenarios...I'm sorry but without seeing the actual code, these are all the advices that I can give you.

Comment: There is no object such as mobileauthenticatedstream basically we are calling Web API using asyn and await operator one after another. These APIs depend on each other

Comment: `MobileAuthenticatedStream` Are you using the NSUrlHandler for the HttpClient?

Comment: @SushiHangover No I am not using NSUrlHandler, we are using Managed(Default). Does it causing the problem ?